# OneDrive Personal seems to stop processing

Tags: onedrive

I see this very often, I install OneDrive (Personal) on a system, then it starts doing things, but then after a few days, it just goes into what looks like a stuck state where I will see messages like the following that just never change. i.e. it says that it is "processing" many thousands of changes, but that figure never changes for days, including if I reboot the system.

I see this very often, including if I completely reinstall Windows, so I'm guessing that a lot of people see this sort of thing, and hopefully someone can tell me how to fix this and get it processing changes again please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be happening to many people.

The Microsoft article
[OneDrive is stuck on Processing changes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/onedrive-is-stuck-on-processing-changes-b386b813-9b66-4e47-8c4c-2b45533edccd)
advises to analyze the problem by selecting the white or blue
OneDrive cloud icon in the taskbar/menu bar to show the list of all
files being synced or have recently synced.

The article contains several cases and some advice for each.
To boil down this advice:

- Do not sync very large files
- Pausing and resuming the sync
- Temporary or hidden files may be blocking sync
- Reset OneDrive or see the article for other fixes.

The article
[OneDrive Stuck on Preparing to Upload](https://www.cbackup.com/articles/onedrive-preparing-to-upload.html)
adds some more:

- Check if the current file name is too long or contains invalid characters
- You have reached your daily upload limit
- OneDrive space is exhausted
- Unchecking files on demand may help.

The article
[OneDrive Stuck on Processing Changes | 8 Quick Fixes](https://www.cbackup.com/articles/onedrive-stuck-on-processing-changes.html)
adds some more solutions, but the one that seems different is to
delete a file named `000A0000-A000-A000-0A0A-00000A0A000A`
from the OneDrive folder.

I have not included all the advice from the above articles, just the ones
that seemed to me to be likelier to help.
You may also search for more articles, as many users of OneDrive has faced
the same problem, but for different reasons.

There exist also third-party
[alternatives for OneDrive](https://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-onedrive/)
that are less problematic.

Comment: Thanks for this Harry, it's great, but so far I've still not been able to get this to fix the issue. If I can find one of these working, I will report back and mark as the correct answer. It is frustrating how commonly I see this issue with OneDrive...